# How to maintain multiple cordova versions in development system?

Tags: cordova, cordova-plugins

How can we maintain multiple versions of Cordova in a system . We develop multiple applications and my system currently runs **3.6.3-0.2.12** . But another application that is in development works only upto Cordova v3.5. Is it possible to maintain multiple versions of cordova in one system ?

Answer (score 11):

You can do it. Typically, you would install cordova globally with `npm install -g cordova`. This install drops an executable in the global npm directory that is in your PATH and the application is ready to use. You can install the cordova cli locally with `npm install --save cordova@3.5` which will install the CLI tool in the working directory at `./node_modules/cordova` and add the dependency to your package.json

Now (on a windows machine at least) there is a hidden `.bin` directory in the node_modules folder. You can access the local cordova cli here

```
node_modules/.bin/cordova.cmd create myproject com.site.myprojectMyProject
```

You could create a script in your project's root folder to relay commands to the local install.

Answer (score 5):

**UPDATE:** As of npm@5.2.0, there's an `npx` command (see [here](https://medium.com/@maybekatz/introducing-npx-an-npm-package-runner-55f7d4bd282b)) that will let you invoke locally-installed CLI commands like `cordova` directly without creating an npm pass-through script or requiring `--` to pass args, like this:

`> npx cordova <args>`

**PREVIOUS PRE-NPM@5.2.0 ANSWER:**

Fortunately, you can manage multiple cordova versions via local project installs without having to install cordova globally. Since `npm run` adds `node_modules/.bin` to the PATH provided to scripts in *package.json*, you can just add scripts there for common cordova tasks, as well as add a simple `"cordova": "cordova"` catch-all script to pass through ad hoc commands:

*scripts section in package.json:*

```
"scripts": {
  ...
  "build:android": "cordova build android",
  "cordova": "cordova",
  ...
}
```

To pass arguments through to the `cordova` (or any npm) script, use `--` as a separator, like this:

> npm run cordova -- platform add android

Without the `--`, the argument is assumed to be for `npm` itself and not passed to the script. For example,

> npm run cordova -v

shows the version for npm itself, because it's never passed through to cordova! To see the local cordova version, do this:

> npm run cordova -- -v

I've found that this *package.json* scripts-based approach makes it easy to manage multiple versions of CLI tools like cordova, ionic, etc., across projects, and I rarely install global packages anymore except for non-project-specific utilities that are convenient to have available everywhere (e.g. mkdirp, rimraf, etc.).

Answer (score 1):

To piggy-back on the answer from @codevision, you could have an older cordova CLI version and install later **platforms**.  This would allow you to keep a global CLI for multiple cordova projects, yet have them run on older or later platforms.  To add a specific platform, for example, you can run `cordova platform add android@6.3.0`

You likely can't install older platforms than your CLI version, but you certainly can install platforms **newer** than your CLI version.

Answer (score 0):

When developing Cordova you have to clearly distinguish the version of Cordova CLI and versions for each platform which you use during development. From your question seems that you have Cordova CLI running 3.6.3 and want to develop using that CLI for existing project running Cordova platforms version 3.5

Answer on this question is - yes, you able to develop, build, add plugins and run you application with platforms which was created using Cordova CLI 3.5, but you can't add platforms version 3.5 using CLI 3.6.3.
Your application would be upgraded to 3.6.3 only when you run commands `cordova platform ios update` (iOS taken for example, same for other platforms), so if you have your **platforms** folder in your VCS, you are safe to go.

**WARNING:** If you don't put you **platforms** code in the VCS, then any new developer, or any new checkout from source control in clean working copy produce application which will be using Cordova platforms version 3.6.3 which is probably not what you want.